# XML to Pandas Dataframe conversion

Tags: xml, pandas, elementtree

XML File :

```
<start>
    <Hit>
         <hits path="xxxxx" id="xx" title="xxx">
         <hits path="aaaaa" id="aa" title="aaa">
    </Hit>
    <Hit>
         <hits path="bbbbb" id="bb" title="bbb">
    </Hit>
    <Hit>
         <hits path="qqqqq" id="qq" title="qqq">
         <hits path="wwwww" id="ww" title="www">
         <hits path="ttttt" id="tt" title="ttt">
    </Hit>
</start>
```

Python code :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(xml_data)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    record = child.attrib.values()
    all_records.append(record)
    pd1 = pd.DataFrame(all_records,columns=subchild.attrib.keys())
```

I have unstructed XML file. **Hit** element can have random number of sub **hits** elements.

 I want to make a list of all the first **hits** sub element from all **Hit** element.

 Answer :

 Dataframe content :

```
   path    id    title
0  xxxxx   xx    xxx
1  bbbbb   bb    bbb
2  qqqqq   qq    qqq
```

That's it. All the other items should be ignored.

```
record = child.attrib.values()
```

This line of code is taking all the values form **hits** element. i.e. total 6 values. I want only 3 values as only 3 **Hit** tag is available.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need change:

```
record = child.attrib.values()
```

to:

```
record = child[0].attrib.values()
```

for select only first values.

List comprehesnion solution:

```
all_records = [child[0].attrib.values() for child in root ]
```

---

If possible some empty `Hit` elements:

```
all_records = []
for child in root:
    if len(child) > 0:
        record = child[0].attrib.values()
        all_records.append(record)
```

List comprehension solution:

```
all_records = [child[0].attrib.values() for child in root if len(child) > 0]
```